# How to move Timestamp from One Button Click to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

Currently for our Company Management System when have a bug for time-stamping a 'MarketTrial' before mass production.

Under 'MarketTrial Details' the user is able to edit Size, Sets, Sections before submitting the entry form via an 'Insert' Link button. I would also like to add that when a size is selected this also automatically edits  the 'end date'

Once the  'Insert' link button is selected this date is then timestamped under the 'MartketTrial Details' however my intentions is that this date should not be timestamped until the 'Submit for Mass' is selected after Market Trial Details and other Data Entry fields are completed within the whole form.

Below is the code for the 'Insert' link Button

```vb
Protected Sub Insert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim strEDate As String
    With odMarketTrial

        .InsertParameters("Row").DefaultValue = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("lblRowInsert"), Label).Text
        .InsertParameters("Size").DefaultValue = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSizeEditF"), TextBox).Text
        .InsertParameters("Sets").DefaultValue = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("ddSetsInsert"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        .InsertParameters("Sections").DefaultValue = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("ddSectionsInsert"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        .InsertParameters("Type").DefaultValue = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("ddType"), DropDownList).SelectedValue

        .InsertParameters("EndDate").DefaultValue = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDateInsert"), TextBox).Text 

        strEDate = CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDateInsert"), TextBox).Text
        If strEDate = "" Or Not IsDate(strEDate ) Or (DateTime.Compare(Now, strEDate ) > 0) Then
            'If CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDateInsert"), TextBox).Text = "" Then
            lblRequestedDateError.Visible = True
            lblRequestedDateError.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            'ElseIf isValidDate(CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDateInsert"), TextBox).Text) Then
        Else
            lblendDateError.Visible = False
            lblendDateError.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If

        If lblDRFStatus.Text = "" Then
            .InsertParameters("LBSStatus").DefaultValue = "0 -"
        Else
            .InsertParameters("LBSStatus").DefaultValue = lblLBSStatus.Text
        End If
        .Insert()
    End With

    Session.Add("Redirect", "LBS")
    LBS_Action()

End Sub
```

So I would like to know how I can transfer the data entry for 'EndDate' from 'Insert' to 'Submit for Mass' as so far my main obstacle has been that once 'Insert' is clicked the data wont submit as there is no date present in the 'txtEndDateInsert'

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.InsertParameters("EndDate").DefaultValue = If(string.IsNullorEmpty(CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDateInsert"), TextBox).Text), DateString, CType(gvmtrial.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDateInsert"), TextBox).Text)
```